# Joomla Contact Form's and some of RS Form's fields aren't editable (disabled)

Tags: joomla-3.x, rsform, widgetkit

I've noticed that Joomla Contact Form's and some of RS Form's fields aren't editable (disabled). I think it's probably because of incorrect Joomla ACL settings for public access to the fields, but I don't know exactly how to fix it.

<sub>**Moderator note**: Links to live site were removed because the links were broken and after the problem was repaired, the links of course would fail to present the old problem.  All problems which rely on visualising a user interface should capture the problem as a static screenshot -- not a link to the live site.</sub>

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer so we can see your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Widgetkit seems to have solved the issue....

Comment: Please award the green tick to your resolving answer.